# Java Generics <this??>

Tags: java

Is there any way you could use a type of the class you're in for a generic argument? for example I have this class `ServiceNode`

```
public final class ServiceNode<S extends NetworkService> {

    private final S service;
    private final Client client;
    private Object attachment;

    public ServiceNode(S service, Client client) {
        this (service, client, null);
    }

    public ServiceNode(S service, Client client, Object attachment) {
        this.service = service;
        this.client = client;
        this.attachment = attachment;
    }

    public S service() {
        return service;
    }

....

}
```

which is a part of the abstract class `NetworkService`

```
public abstract class NetworkService {

    private final Set<ServiceNode<?>> registeredNodes = new HashSet<>();

    public final void register(ServiceNode<?> node) {
        registeredNodes.add(node);
    }

    ...

}
```

So basically is there anyway to remove the wildcard argument from `ServiceNode` in the `NetworkService` class and replace it with whatever type the class is extending `NetworkService`

Comment: If I may ask -- why make a concrete class depend "type wise" on its outer class?

Answer (score 16):

Genericise your base class thus:

```
public abstract class NetworkService<T extends NetworkService<T>> {

    private final Set<ServiceNode<T>> registeredNodes;

    ...
}
```

and then extend from it thus:

```
public class MyNetworkService extends NetworkService<MyNetworkService> {
    ...
}
```

Google for *curiously recurring generic pattern*.